# jQuery ajax-call to upload file in spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, image-uploading

How to make use of ajax call with jQuery to upload image to database in java using spring mvc? I guess fileUpload is not supported below IE9. Is there any way to make us of ajax call which will support IE8 and above?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far! And please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: search for file upload with hidden iframe

Comment: Take a look at this: http://kaushikghosh12.blogspot.com/2014/02/ajax-fileupload-on-all-browsers.html